# Member ( as admin role ) can able to post image in FB groups using api or not?

Tags: php, facebook, feed, facebook-group

I have developed page for posting feed in facebook group using API. But In that the group admin can only able to post feeds. But i want that the member who is assigned as admin role can able to post. There is any possible to mamber can post?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What is the difference between “the” group admin, and any member that is also an admin, by your definition? An account either is an admin of a group, or not.

Comment: I Am a FB group member i want to post feeds under the Group(which am a member) using FB graph API

Comment: So just a normal member, not a group admin? Then it depends on the group type - public, or private/closed, whether they can post via API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/feed explains all that, have you not read it …?